# How to hide table from Access database 2007

Tags: c#, ms-access

how to hide the table in Access database so that user can't access that table?

Comment: Atleast try some thing and ask here.....

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest protection mechanisms in Access 2007 is to hide important objects. To do this, in the Navigation Pane, right-click an object and select Table Properties or View Properties (for all other objects). Now select the Hidden property, and the object disappears from the Navigation Pane.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb421308(v=office.12).aspx